# intellij typescript live edit

Tags: typescript, angular, edit, live

How would I do this ?
Setting it up works as I can edit the index.html file.
But everything changed within the angular2 application doesn't live-reload/show/edit.

I've googled and asked on gitter with no succes.
Searching within setting's didn't help me neither.

Has anyone an idea or suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack hotswap seems the only 'pluasible' solution.
Setting it up by the time of writing.

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter
https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack